# how to redirect a URL to a new browser window using sendRedirct(URL)?

Tags: url, servlets, spring-mvc

I am using a Spring, where i try to response.redirect to a new window. i am not able do it. it just calls the urL in the same browser window. how do i make redirect to a new window..?

is there any other options to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that server-side only.

You can make the request itself in a new window using the `target` attribute of `<a>` or `<form>`:

```
<form target="_blank">..</form>
```

Or you can use ajax:

1. request a resource
2. return (print as response) the desired target url
3. use `window.location.href = returnedUrl`

Comment: i dont know how to use ajax, any other suggestion sir ?

Comment: @ayyappa - there is another one in the answer - make the request itself in a new window. How are you making the request? using <a href=.. ?

Comment: i am calling  sendRedirect(URL) in Spring onSubmit(res,req,.,.) when sunmit button is clicked from the JSP . it returns the page as URL i want to display success page back instead of URL page.

Comment: there is a problem.. when it redirects to the new windows, the controller doesnt have the request parameters of the previous window.

Comment: @ayyappa of course. http is non-session protocol. For each request you need to pass the parameters anew.